# What does the usage of restrict mean in the man page for 'fwrite'?

Tags: c, void-pointers, type-safety, restrict-qualifier

I was looking a the man page for fwrite, and I was curious about the usage of restrict for the arguments as I have no seen this before.

```
size_t fwrite(const void ptr[restrict .size * .nmemb]...
```

what does the `.size * .nmemb` mean here? are we restricting the allowed size of `ptr`?

I was hoping I could use this to better my own code in terms of safety when using void pointers.

Thanks :D

Comment: this is just how it displays in my terminal when i use `man fwrite`

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Some man pages. For example, https://man.archlinux.org/man/fwrite.3.en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`restrict` is a keyword indicating that no other argument should point to or be found in an area of the buffer pointed by `ptr`. This allows optimizations.

`.size * .nmemb` is pseudocode indicating the size of the buffer is expected to be (at least) as big as the result of the multiplication of value of the `size` and `nmemb` parameters.